# A modern tool on OSX that directs links from other apps automatically to different browsers

Tags: osx, web-browser

Looking for a modern tool on OSX that directs links from other apps automatically to different browsers. Kind of a middle man taking the spot of the default browser and then automatically directing the link to a real browser like Firefox, Chrome or Safari.

I want to create rules depending on link patterns and or source application where the link get directed to: e.g., "Local (file) links go to Safari", "Links from Mail go to Chrome" and "All other links go to Firefox".

I found [Choosy](http://www.choosyosx.com/) and it does what I want it to do, but it is rather old, not recently maintained (last build is from 2009) and has some glitches with OSX Spaces.

So I am looking for another, a *modern* tool directing websites to different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I wrote my own tool for this: [Brosel](https://github.com/halloleo/brosel) It does not have a GUI, but the redirection rules live in a plain text file and are easily edited.